# Why do I have errors on OnCreateBundle, OnCreateOptionsMenu, OnOptionsItemSelected?

Tags: java, oncreate

I'm really new to this, so I am a bit confused.  I have multiple errors. I'm only starting the project. And I'm using Eclipse on Virtual Box.
Here is my java code:

```
 package com.example.module7;
import com.example.module7.*;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Thanks!!!!

Comment: please post the error messages you get.

Comment: What do the errors say?